# Table content overflowing div

Tags: html, css

Issue: I have a table inside div, table has few inputs elements. when I resize the browser window or change the windows to a low resolution the div element resizes and scales down and also horizontal scroll bar appear, but the table overflows its parent div. for example the below code shows the issue if you resize the browser window

fiddle- http://jsfiddle.net/CrfaE/573

code-

```
<html>
<body>
 <div style="border: 1px solid orange; padding: 1px">
  <span>level1</span>
  <div style="border: 1px solid blue; padding: 1px">
     <span>level2</span>
    <div style="border: 1px solid green; padding: 1px">
        <span>level3</span>
        <table style="border: 1px solid red;">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>

                    <td><input value="2017-01-01"></td>
                    <td><input value="abc"></td>
                    <td><input value="3"></td>
                    <td><select>
                            <option value="">Select</option>
                            <option>abc</option>
                            <option>def</option>
                            <option>ghi</option>
                    </select></td>
                    <td><input value="10"></td>
                    <td><input value=""></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
 </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Required behavior : The parent div element and all its parent div elements should resize/expand such that table does not overflows and user is able to see the page using browser's horizontal scroll bars. i.e. a horizontal scroll bar appears but all the divs stretches and  table does not overflows div/body

Comment: The table is being generated dynamically and it just distorts the UI

Comment: @Rob In Chrome resize the window to smaller size, it looks good in normal window, but if you resize the browser to smaller size you can see the issue. or refer to jsfiddle where also you can see the issue http://jsfiddle.net/CrfaE/573

Comment: Would you be okay with a horizontal scroll bar right under the table?

Comment: @Dream_Cap No that would look weird, I had thought about that solution also.

Comment: @saipadam You can apply `position:absolute` to the first div and that should fix the issue.

Comment: @PhaniKumarM This looks like one of the solution. But I am bit hesitant of using absolute, on a big complex page setting absolute to the topmost level element. how does it changes/ interferes the positioning where curen it is default(i.e. relative). Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @saipadam Other options would be `float:left` or `display:inline-block` for the first div.

Comment: @PhaniKumarM these will work in this particular case, but in case we have an html which is more complex then that for example where the root has many other elements also consider this table is just a leaf element so there would be many other leafs or inner nodes.  so in such case fixing this at the root level would impact others...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I hope help you:**

1)Insert `type="text"` to `input` elements.

2)insert this css code:

```
input[type="text"] {
    width: 100%;//width relative to her parent(td Element).
}
```

```css
table {
 border: 2px solid red;
}
input[type="text"] {
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/1.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div  style="border: 1px solid orange; padding: 1px">
  <span>level1</span>
  <div style="border: 1px solid blue; padding: 1px">
     <span>level2</span>
    <div style="border: 1px solid green; padding: 1px">
        <span>level3</span>
        <div class="respon">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td><input value="2017-01-01" type="text"></td>
                    <td><input value="abc" type="text"></td>
                    <td><input value="3" type="text"></td>
                    <td><select>
                            <option value="">Select</option>
                            <option>abc</option>
                            <option>def</option>
                            <option>ghi</option>
                    </select></td>
                    <td><input value="10" type="text"></td>
                    <td><input value="" type="text"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank You! @ehsan. The solution worked perfectly fine.